# Why do slow downloads via PHP stop after an hour while direct download of the same files do not?

Tags: php, download

We do not allow users to download files directly (payed files). If the user has a slow connection and the download does take a long time it breaks at about 60-70 minutes (the server closes the connection. If the same download is done directly (directly accessing the file URL instead of sending it via PHP) the download works just fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Why was this moved to SO? This is clearly not a programming question, but a question regarding configuration/setup of a webserver. What is the reasoning behind the move?

Comment: Probably because it's a PHP question. Might be better on Server Fault though

Comment: Well, it is not a PHP-language question. It's more of a setup question (which is on topic in webmasters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a PHP configuration parameter called max_execution_time that sets the maximum time a PHP script can run before it times out. The default value is 30 seconds, but I suspect yours is set to around 60 minutes.

Comment: max_execution_time is set to 7200 (2h)

Comment: There are other parameters to consider too, such as memory_limit. But downloading as large php files is generally a bad idea. A better idea would be generate a file and use .htaccess to force that url to download with a certain header.

Comment: Not "downloading as large php files". The file is read via php and sent to the browser.